# using spring, can I extract some part of a static method to use to set a property on a bean?

Tags: java, spring

I have a static method I have no control over: `MyUtils.getServiceURL()` which returns a URL. I need to extract just the port from this URL to set a property on a bean:

```
<bean id="myBean>
   <property name="defaultPort" value="?????"/>
</bean>
```

I can get the string value of the URL as a bean like this:

```
<bean id="serviceURL" class="MyUtils" factory-method="getServiceURL" />
```

I'm probably just going to write a method to parse the URL in `myBean` and extract the port. I was wondering if there was a way to avoid having to do this, and configure this directly in the spring context?

Comment: Treat a java.net.URL as a bean (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for custom classes, or parsers. Remember, a bean is just a class with get/is/set methods. A `java.net.URL` class qualifies as such.

Solution: Use a `java.net.URL` as a Spring-configurable bean and call it's `getPort` method.

Remember, in Spring, you can wire anything as a *bean* very easily so long as it sports methods using the *get/is/set* Bean convention. The java.net.URL class does such a thing.

** warning ** I'm just typing this out of my a$$, you'll have to check for any syntax shenanigans that I might be introducing in this Spring-config pseudo-code. One thing that is certain is that the concept will work with Spring 2.5 and that it relies on the `util` schema.

If you are using an older version of Spring, you'll have to use a `PropertyPathFactoryBean`. If you are using Spring 3.0, you'll want to use Spring expression language (EL), but I can't comment on the later since I'm not familiar with Spring 3.0.

*In java*:

```
int port = (new URL(MyUtils.getServiceURL()).getPort()
```

*In Spring*:

```
<bean id="serviceURL" class="MyUtils" factory-method="getServiceURL" />

<bean id="myURL" class="java.net.URL">
  <constructor-arg>
    <ref-bean="serviceURL"/>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<util:property-path id="defaultPort" path="myURL.port"/>

<bean id="myBean>
    <property name="defaultPort" ref="defaultPort"/>
</bean>
```

There might be a way to consolidate all these four expressions into three or less, don't know if that will improve readability, though. The concept remains the same, though. Treat a `java.net.URL` instance as a bean, set its URL via its constructor, and get a hold (via Spring) of its `getPort()` method.

---

** edit **:
If you are using Spring 2.5 you can create an inline groovy bean that does all that for you. I've seen people doing that as *integration glue* to get rid of multitude of *temp* Spring bean place holders. That's the best choice IMO when you need to define a class (when it's simpler than just using Spring tags) and when you know such a class won't be used outside of Spring wiring of things.

Answer (score 1):

Not I can think of. Either way, you probably have to write something to parse the port out. Since you have no control of that static method, perhaps you may want to utilize the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to hide that static method. Doing so also makes your code easier to test because you can easily mock that external API out. For example:-

```
public interface URLServiceAdapter {
    int getServiceURLPort();
}

public class URLServiceAdapterImpl implements URLServiceAdapter {
    public int getServiceURLPort() {
        return MyUtils.getServiceURL().getPort();
    }
}
```

Your beans will then rely on your adapter class instead of `MyUtils.getServiceURL()` directly:-

```
<bean id="urlServiceAdapter" class="project.URLServiceAdapterImpl" />
```

That way, you can do something like this:-

```
@Autowired
private UrlServiceAdapter urlServiceAdapter;

...

bean.setDefaultPort(urlServiceAdapter.getServiceURLPort());
```

Comment: Thanks @limc, I like the idea of using an adapter. I wanted to avoid polluting my bean with the notion of a URL; which it shouldn't care about.

Answer (score 1):

SpEL is your friend.

```
<bean id="myBean>
    <property name="defaultPort" 
     value='#{ T(com.foo.MyUtils).getServiceURL().split(":")[2].split("/")[0] }'/>
</bean>
```

Enjoy,